# List orders which all rows are ready

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my orders table. I want to report all orders which all details are Ready For Shipment.

```
orderNo detailNo    statusId    status  
10001   1           40        Ready For Shipment
10002   1           40        Ready For Shipment
10002   2           20        Canceled
10002   3           30        Pending
10003   1           40        Ready For Shipment
10003   2           40        Ready For Shipment
10004   1           10        New Order
10004   2           20        Canceled
10004   3           40        Ready For Shipment
10004   4           40        Ready For Shipment
```

Expected results are:

```
Orders Ready For Shipment
10001 
10003
```

Are there any effective method to achieve ready orders list without using subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the `orderno` and use a `having`to get only those groups having no other status

```
select orderno
from your_table
group by orderno
having sum(case when status <> 'Ready For Shipment' then 1 end) = 0
```

or with the `statusId`

```
select orderno
from your_table
group by orderno
having sum(case when statusid <> 40 then 1 end) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you, worked with a small modification. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Distinct a.orderId 
from ordersTable a
inner join 
(
   select orderNo, Avg(statusId)
   from ordersTable
   group by orderNo
   having Avg(statusId) = 40) b
on a.orderNo = b.orderNo
```

Comment: @juergen's answer worked for me, because I was searching a solution with no sub queries. thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT orderNo from <TABLE NAME> 
WHERE status="Ready For Shipment" ORDER BY orderNo
```